# Using Variables from a list 1 as a input in a loop from list 2

Tags: python, loops

So i have
List one:

```
NumberOfLoops = 5
for x in range(1, NumberOfLoops + 1):
    listSONO.append(f'{BaseSONO}-{x:0>2}')
```

Output:

```
['AutoSO_May042022-01', 'AutoSO_May042022-02', 'AutoSO_May042022-03', 'AutoSO_May042022-04', 'AutoSO_May042022-05']
```

List two:

```
tote = ['T' + "%.5d" % i for i in range(1, NumberOfLoops + 1)]
```

Output:

```
['T00001', 'T00002', 'T00003', 'T00004', 'T00005']
```

i trigger a for loop by using the items on the first list but i dont know how to use corespoding items from the second as variables in the loop

For instance

Use **AutoSO_May042022-01** in field xyz and **T00001** in field abc and repeat that for as many times the number of items in the first list.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I'm sorry ill try to clarify because i see i didn't explain it well enough:

Say list1 are my logins and list2 are the passwords i would like to circle through all Logins and all Passwords 1 by 1. So send those items to a variable i have in my code that is responsible for the txt i input in the "Password" and "Login" respectfully.

So how do i make for example
first loop where:
a = AutoSO_May042022-01 (first position on first list)
b = T00001 (first position on second list)
Second loop where:
a = second position on first list
b = second position on second list

and so on

Comment: It's not clear how you want to combine the two lists. Use `zip()` to loop over them in parallel, use nested loops or `itertools.product()` to get a cross product.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understood, you want to iterate through both lists simultaneously. For this you can use zip().

```
for f, b in zip(foo, bar):
    print(f, b)
```

This question is answered here [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: If the question is completely answered in another question, just flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: yeah well, its not - at least i don't think it is